# Mozilla Firefox Headless Screenshot not working for local HTML files

Tags: firefox, webpage-screenshot, firefox-headless

I'm unable to generate a screenshot of a local HTML file using Firefox's (v60.9.0) [headless mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Headless_mode)

Here's the command I'm using:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -P AJ --screenshot test.png "file:///C:/html_export.html"
```

I've tried with and without a profile and with different numbers of slashes after file. There are no errors in the command line - it just doesn't generate an output.

This command works fine when I substitute the file:// with an external website like:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -P AJ --screenshot test.png google.com
```

Could it be related to the [redirect bug mentioned here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1546062)?

Any help is appreciated! Perhaps theres a way to turn on output verbosity for --headless mode?

Comment: No answer, but you can always run a local server. PHP, Python and Node.js all come with servers for testing, that can be run with one command from the command line. (e.g. php -S localhost:8080 )